# Checking if date falls in a specified month in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
procedure Charge(p_inputdate   N VARCHAR2,//Date which accepts only MMYYYY format
                   inout_Cur OUT result_cur) IS
```

I need to validate the effective_date which is in date format (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)

For example: The user enters `112013` as input and the effective date to check is `11/12/2013 09:13:22`

Is  it possible to find whether the effective date falls within the specified month?

can you please comment on this..

> > > I tried below way:
> >
> > V_INPUTDATE := to_char(TO_DATE(IN_INPUTDATE, 'MMYYYY','mmyyyy'));
> >
> > v_effectiveDate := substr(V_INPUTDATE,1,2)+'/'+'01'+'/'+substr(V_INPUTDATE,3,4);

01 is nothing but month always start with 01(dd)
Is this rightway ..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If date happens to be a `VARCHAR2` you need to first convert it to DATE:

```
effective_date DATE;  -- Put this line in the declare section

effective_date := to_date('11/12/2013 09:13:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

When you have the date, the rest is easy:

```
IF p_inputdate = to_char(effective_date, 'MMYYYY') THEN
    -- Date is ok.
ELSE 
    -- Date is not ok.
END IF;
```